# C++ public inheritance [SFML]

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I've been having trouble drawing a sprite of hero to the screen(which I solved with a different approach). Problem was caused because of inheritance. Now I'm gonna put all the code and tell the story alongside with codes.

Character.h (the parent class for hero and npcs)

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "TextureHolder.h"

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
class Character
{
protected:
    Vector2f m_Position;
    int m_Speed;

public:
    Character();
    void spawn(int x, int y, string direction);
    Sprite m_Sprite;
    Texture m_Texture;

    void virtual update(float elapsedTime);

};
```

Character.cpp has nothing except constructor and update function declerations

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Character.h"
Character::Character(){}
void Character::update(float elapsedTime) {}
```

Hero.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Character.h"
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
class Hero : public Character
{
private:

public:
    Hero();
    void virtual update(float elapsedTime);

};
```

And finally Hero.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Hero.h"

Hero::Hero()
{
    m_Texture = TextureHolder::GetTexture("images/chars/hero.png");
    m_Sprite.setTexture(m_Texture);
}

void Hero::update(float elapsedTime)
{

}
```

With the classes this way, When I try to draw hero.m_Sprite it gives access violation.

As you see I'm using public inheritance from character to hero(which should have worked perfectly, since when I type "hero." it shows me list of it's public members and m_sprite is among them)

But when I try to add m_Sprite and m_Texture in Hero.h(instead of inheriting them from Character class , I got no errors.

What is the reason behind this?

**Edit:** draw.cpp

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "Engine.h"


void Engine::draw()
{
    m_Window.clear(Color::Black);

    m_Window.setView(m_MainView);



    m_Window.draw(hero.m_Sprite);



    m_Window.display();

}
```

**EDIT 2:** IT doesn't give errors anymore. I didn't change anything and I don't have any idea what caused and what fixed the problem.

Comment: Small note: `using` declarations in headers are *very* bad. Please put them in the source file or don't use them altogether (not always possible though).

Comment: I'm fairly new to c++, why is it bad to use "using" on headers?

Comment: Have a look at [those answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232496/is-it-wrong-to-use-c-using-keyword-in-a-header-file).

Comment: how are you accessing the object? is it through a pointer, base class, derived class or what?

Comment: @JasonLang I got a draw.cpp file , let me add it through edit.

Comment: you don't wanna have an sf::Texture in every instance of every character/hero/enemy etc. right now you copy textures when you get them from your texture holder. You probably want a reference.