# How to return a value of a type aliased in a class?

Tags: c++

I have a templated class and an aliased type. I want to use this type as a return value of a member function, but it doesn't compile.

```
//file.h
template<class T>
class Test {
public:
    using testing = T;
    T value;
    testing foo();
};

//file.cpp
template<class T>
testing Test<T>::foo() { //error 'testing' does not name a type
    //code
}
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of `foo` by:

```
template<class T>
typename Test<T>::testing Test<T>::foo() {
}
```

or even less verbose as suggested by @Jarod42

```
template<class T>
auto Test<T>::foo() -> testing {
}
```

Also you should read [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: or `template<class T> auto Test<T>::foo() -> testing`.

Answer (score 1):

Using directives in header files should be avoided, because usually they will bring trouble in larger codebases [Is it wrong to use C++ 'using' keyword in a header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232496/is-it-wrong-to-use-c-using-keyword-in-a-header-file)

But the real problem I see here is that you try to split the template class' implementation off to a cpp file. This only works, resp. links, if you go a long way with workarounds most devs would consider bad practice or at least unexpected/unrequired https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/%2FArticles%2F48575%2FHow-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp

So I'd say put the implementation to the header file, don't use using there and you are fine and it would be the expected way to implement a template class.

What you could use instead to make your life easier there and give things better names is typedef.

Comment: `using namespace` != `typedef` (even with `using`).

Comment: I'm not saying using can not be used, I'm saying it's bad practice in a header file. And I'm not saying it's the same as typedef, but it's a valid way to make your life easier if you really have to like typedef std::list<T> type;

Comment: I meant that OP doesn't use `using namespace`, so it is fine (having alias in class is common practice and not bad). It is like if you said that we should avoid names beginning with double underscore as reserved. Even if true, it is not relevant to OP who doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The template method has to be implemented in the header.

Answer (score 0):

`testing` does not mean anything unless it is associated with Test

You need put both in the header file (`file.h`) and it is easier when these functions are declared in the same class:

```
template<class T>
class Test {
public:
    using testing = T;
    T value;

    testing foo() 
    {
        return testing();
    }
};
```